# How to compare dates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the current date in the cell "AP2" and a column (N) with several dates. If Current date is higher then values entailed in column N, I need that vba macro count that values lower then current date. But it doesn't work with this formula. Any suggests.

```
If Cells(1 + x, 1) = "@3J@" Or Cells(1 + x, 1) = "@5D@" And **Range("AP2") > Cells(1 + x, 14) And Cells(1 + x, 14) <> "" Then
    Counter_A01_incorsdata = Counter_A01_incorsdata + 1**
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" stand for actually?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub Flavio()
    Dim n&
    n = [countifs(n:n,"<"&ap2)]
    MsgBox n
End Sub
```